# How do I position a GridPanel inside an Ext.NET window?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

I can't seem to set the position of an Ext.NET GridPanel inside an Ext.NET window  and I wonder why?

```
<ext:Window ID="Window1" runat="server" StripeRows="true" Width="900" Height="700"
    Closable="false" Collapsible="true" Maximizable="true" Layout="Fit" 
    X="0" Y="0"
    CenterOnLoad="false">
    <Items>
        <ext:GridPanel ID="customersGrid" runat="server" />
     //.....................
```

When I change X and Y it doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the GridPanel to be absolutely positioned somewhere inside the Window, you'll have to set Layout="Absolute" on the `<ext:Window>`, and set the .X and .Y properties of the `<ext:GridPanel>`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think Layout="Fit" gives you issue, check that..

Comment: check constraintoviewport  property if exist then set it false and use moveto method in code behind there one more element Ext.Element check it too.

Comment: and check this URL it will help you,http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/Setcontrolxyposition.htm